# Difference in using `start from` and `start with`

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in using `start from` and `start with` in sentences like this:

```
You can buy a lot of things there starting from food and finishing with clothes.
```

There is a related [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112972/starting-with-vs-starting-from), but the context is different.

Comment: I think neither is appropriate in this context, because you might as well start at cloths. I would prefer "*with*" simply because the repetition rhymes, if I had to chose. "*from*" or others seem to indicate a place, as answered below. It might be influenced by "from A to Z", which I think would be simpler. As answered, also, "*to start from*" narrows the meaning of "*from*", i.e. disambiguating it from "delivered by*".

Comment: Using "from" makes me try to imagine food turning into clothes.  Like tree starts from a seed and ends as wood.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264839/from-soup-to-nuts, which also covers "start to finish.".  I'd simplify: _You can buy a lot of things there, from food to clothing._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start From indicates a position or marker to reference within a sequence.

Start With indicates a set of ingredients, an *a priori* position, or an asserted condition.

There's also Start At, or Start On - similar to Start From

Examples: 
*We started with the grocery aisles, and had a full cart by housewares*

*Start from scratch* - redo a process from the beginning rather than back up a step or two and try again.

*Start with the basics* - don't assume prior knowledge or experience.

*Starting on pole position (racing)* - enumerate the lead item and then down the list

*Start at the beginning, and when you reach the end, stop* - Read the whole account and don't leave anything out